# Fedora 26 hangs on reboot

Tags: linux, fedora, nfs, linux-kernel

I'm using fedora 26 and i keep getting these weird hangs on reboot, they are not consistent (I can reboot 20 times and it would work fine, and reboot 20 times again and it will hang).

The last message im getting is

> nfsd last server has exited flushing export cache

I've tried a few things while trying to debug it -

Disabled nfs, Disabled watchdog, different grub entries, all without any success.

I'm working on Supermicro x9 and x10.

Did any of you encounter such a problem with fedora 26? (Needless to say it only happens with that version, all other fedora's works fine and Redhat/Centos etc).

Comment: run a memory test. reset your motherboard (write down settings first).